# Mobile Web app with JQuery Mobile and C sharp

Tags: c#, jquery, mobile, web

Hi I'm thinking of developing a mobile web app. I was wondering if it is possible to create the front-end of the application using JQuery Mobile and create the Back-end using C Sharp that will connect to an SQL Server. This app will be based on a 3 Tier Structure meaning Presentation Layer, Business Logic Layer and Data Access Layer. All database operations will be done using LINQ.

Comment: Yes you can, but what would make you think that you may not be able to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. In fact, it is common and a good practice to break up your different layers. I recommend that you look at the following: http://www.asp.net/mvc/ -- you can get all the tools you need.

ASP.NET MVC will help break up your Presentation (Views) from your Business Logic (Controllers) and your Data Access Layer becomes your Model.

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo with `jQuery Mobile` and `C#` with DAL of Entity framework at [jquerymobile.codeplex.com](http://jquerymobile.codeplex.com/)